# Identiy missing rows and calculate them in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-scripts, hana-sql-script

I have the follwing data. Need to identify the missing rows and calculate the average

LineNo Field1   Field2  Year    Average
1  France Paris 2019 100 
2  France Paris 2017 300 
3  France Nice 2018 200 
4  Italy        Rome 2019 50 
5  Italy  Rome 2018 500 
6  Italy  Rome    2017 250

Need to calculate the average for all years (2019,2018,2017).

So  for France and Paris combination - Year 2018 is missing.
So for France and Nice - Year  2019 and 2017 is missing.
For Italy and Rome combination, we have all records.

So for missing combination need to calculate the average like below ( formula, sum/3 in all cases, irrespective of number of years present)

The final data looks like below.

LineNo  Field1  Field2  Year    Value
1  France     Paris  2019 100 
2  France     Paris  2017 300 
3  France     Nice   2017 200 
4  Italy  Rome   2019 50 
5  Italy  Rome   2018 500 
6  Italy  Rome   2017 250 
*7 France     Paris  2018 133 
*8 France     Nice   2018 66 
*9 France     Nice   2019 66

Line 7,8,9 are the new ones

Comment: What defines the complete list of years you need to evaluate?  Why isn't 2016 missing from all of them?

Comment: well its basically current year and current year-2

Answer (score 1):

You can use something like below to get the blank row and after that an update statement can update the '0' values to average value

```
SELECT DISTINCT
        [year]
 INTO   #allyears
 FROM   #temp
 -- this is to get all the years in a lookup  
 ;WITH   cte_t
          AS ( SELECT   place1 ,
                        place2 ,
                        CASE WHEN a.year = t.year THEN val
                             ELSE 0
                        END AS val ,
                        a.year ,
                        ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( PARTITION BY place1, place2,
                                            a.year ORDER BY CASE
                                                              WHEN a.year = t.year
                                                              THEN val
                                                              ELSE 0
                                                            END DESC ) rn
               FROM     #allyears AS a
                        CROSS JOIN #temp AS t
             )
    SELECT  place1 ,
            place2 ,
            year ,
            val 
    FROM    cte_t 
    WHERE rn = 1
```